# No PlaceSelectionListener is set. No result will be delivered

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-places-autocomplete

When I clicked the `autocompletefragment`. The log shows:

> Places: No PlaceSelectionListener is set. No result will be
>   delivered.

```
val realView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false)

Places.initialize(activity!!.applicationContext, getString(R.string.google_maps_key))
val placesClient = Places.createClient(activity!!)

val autocompleteFragment1 = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment1) as? AutocompleteSupportFragment // Make casting of 'as' to nullable cast 'as?'

autocompleteFragment1?.setCountry("PH")
// Specify the types of place data to return.
autocompleteFragment1?.setPlaceFields(listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME))

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
autocompleteFragment1?.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
    override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
        Log.d("Hey", place.toString())
    }

    override fun onError(status: Status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.d("HOY", "An error occurred: ${status.statusCode}")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using deprecated code. Try replacing this line:

```
val autocompleteFragment1 = fragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment1) as? AutocompleteSupportFragment // Make casting of 'as' to nullable cast 'as?'
```

With this one:

```
val autocompleteFragment1 = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment1) as? AutocompleteSupportFragment // Make casting of 'as' to nullable cast 'as?
```

Your exact code works on my end after the above change, so I hope this helps!

Comment: If you're experiencing this while using fragments in 2022 then override `onViewCreated` and then Initialize the `AutocompleteSupportFragment` as follows:

`val autocompleteFragment = (this.requireContext() as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment`